# R MySQL data base package

Tags: mysql, r, rstudio

I am trying to install RMySQL package, but cannot find it via the package search utility in RStudio not can I install it via command line .
Do I have the wrong package

Version details:
R 3.0.2
RStudio 0.98.501

thanks

Comment: Please note package name is case sensitive. You can install via command line also  install.packages('RMySQL')

Comment: I installed it (install.packages('RMySQL')) and that went successfully. But then I wanted to load it with library(RMySQL) and it says "there is no package called 'RMySQL' " . What am I missing ?

Comment: end of the installation it will try to load the library,did it return success did you installed with another user, sometimes you can get issues like that if you had installed the packages with root and trying to load it with normal user

Comment: maybe this link can help you http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/

Comment: it says the following warning: "Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)".

Comment: start RStudio as administrator and try again.

Comment: I am running it as administrator...